# Tensorflow: making a ROC curve and confusion matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, tensor

**Background**
I'm tyring to get a grasp of using tensorflow. I currently worte a trainer and tester, although python is no problem for me at all, I can not figure out how to use tensorflow to plot a confusion matrix and ROC curve for my testing. I suppose this could be done quite easily.

---

**Test code**
I prefer to give a reproducible example but I cannot figure out how I should made a model so easy that I can put it here. Therefore if something is unclear please let me know

```
 def test_neural_network(self, test_data, model_name, model_folder):
        x = tf.placeholder('float')
        y = tf.placeholder('float')
        prediction = self.__convolutional_neural_network(x)
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
            saver = tf.train.Saver()

            for epoch in range(self.hm_epochs):
                try:
                    saver.restore(sess,  model_folder + model_name + '.ckpt')
                except Exception as e:
                    print(str(e))

            correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))

            test_data = np.load(test_data)
            features, labels = [],[]
            for item in test_data:
                data = item[0]
                id = item[1]
                features.append(data)
                labels.append(id)
            test_x = np.array(features)
            test_y = np.array(labels)
            print(test_x)
            print(test_y)
            print('Accuracy:', accuracy.eval({x: test_x, y: test_y}))
```

**Question**
Is there any way to visualize this testing in a confusion matrix and ROC curve? Note that I'm familiar with Python but do only superficially understand tensorflow, so an explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough rep to leave a comment, so I will post this as an answer instead. I have used Scikit-Learn's Confusion Matrix functionality to produce error matrices for my own neural network, see: [Confusion Matrix](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html)

Comment: Thankyou, but the question then is how could I obtain the y_pred labels from tensorflow as the accuracy.eval function will not return these (as far as I know)

Comment: I used Keras with a Tensorflow backend, so the syntax is different, but I used a for loop to iterate through all my data and make a prediction for each data sample. I then appended all predictions to a list and saved the list as a Numpy Array. 
Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yeaah I just found it: print(sess.run(tf.argmax(test_y, 1), feed_dict={x: test_x})) now I will use it as input for the code you linked